# Javascript method for rotating images on a mouse click

Tags: javascript

I have a PHP-page with a series of pie chart images (I use [Google Chart Tools](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/docs/gallery/pie_charts.html)) all of the same 700x280 size:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
var chart1 ='http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=bhg&chs=700x280&chd=s:el,or&chco=4d89f9,c6d9fd';
var chart2 ='http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=bhg&chs=700x280&chd=s:el,or&chco=4d89f9,c6d9fd&chbh=15,4,15';
var chart3 ='http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=bvg&chs=700x280&chd=s:hello,world&chco=4d89f9,c6d9fd&chbh=15,4,15';

XXX please suggest a function here XXX
</script>
</head>
<body>
<img src="logo.png" width=700 height=280>

Chart 1:

<img src="http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=p&chd=s:Uf9a&chs=700x280&chl=January|February|March|April" width=700 height=280>

Chart 2:

<img src="http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=p&chd=s:Uf9a&chs=700x280&chdl=May|Juny|July|August" width=700 height=280>

Chart 3:

<img src="http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=p&chd=s:Uf9a&chs=700x280&chl=September|October|November|December" width=700 height=280>

</body>
</html>
```

I would like to offer users the possibility to view the same data as a bar chart - when they click on a chart.

Last time I've used Javascript it had been for MSIE4 and Netscape. Please give me some pointers for my little function.

I.e. I don't need any help with constructing Google Charts, I just need little help on the Javascript function to rotate images in-place, on a mouse click, but with the following requirements:

1) Users with Javascript disabled should be still able to see the pie charts. Also it would be nice to enable them to see the bar charts too (i.e. by putting bar charts behind an HTML-link or maybe you hide the bar charts with Javascript and for users with Javascript disabled they are not hidden - which is okay).

2) Please 1 universal function for all charts - i.e. I don't want to have 10 functions for 10 charts.

Thank you very much! Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Realizing it's ages since I wrote any javascript without a framework (you forgot to mention if you were using one.. You probably should!). Anyway, here's my stab at it. People without Javascript can hover the pie charts to see the bar charts, while people with Javascript can click on them.

```
<style type="text/css">
  img.primary   { display: inline; }
  img.secondary { display: none; }
  div.foo:hover img.secondary { display: inline; }
  div.foo:hover img.primary   { display: none; }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
function swapImages(container)
{
    for(var child in container.childNodes)
    {
        child = container.childNodes[child];
        if(child.nodeName == "IMG")
            child.className = child.className == "primary" ?
                "secondary" : "primary";
    }
}

window.onload = function() {
    // Remove the foo class when the page loads, to disable hover
    var chartArea = document.getElementById("chartArea");
    for(var child in chartArea.childNodes)
    {
        child = chartArea.childNodes[child];
        if(child.nodeName == "DIV" && child.className == "foo")
            child.className = "";
    }
}
</script>

<div id="chartArea">
    <div class="foo" onclick="swapImages(this);">
        <img class="primary" src="http://somewhere/piechart1.png" />
        <img class="secondary" src="http://somewhere/barchart1.png" />
    </div>

    <div class="foo" onclick="swapImages(this);">
        <img class="primary" ... />
        <img class="secondary" ... />    
    </div>

   <div class="foo" ....>
</div>
```

Comment: Awesome solution, thank you! If I'd like to search just in the whole BODY (because my web page is small) instead of the suggested  var chartArea = document.getElementById("chartArea"); how could I do it please? And also I'm curious, what JS framework do you prefer?

Comment: Ok, this seems to work: for (var child in document.body.childNodes)

Comment: You are most welcome. Yes, the only reason I used the chartArea was to reduce the number of elements to loop through - so if your page is small, body's childNodes will work just fine too. As for frameworks, you can't go wrong with jQuery. For bigger single-page applications, you might want to use something with more integrated widgets and build system - I always end up with Dojo, which I'm quite happy with.

Answer (score 0):

If you can live with the image changing on hover instead of on click, you may not need any JavaScript...

```
<style type="text/css">
/*<[CDATA[*/
a.chart,a.chart:hover{
    cursor:default;
    display:block;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    width:700px;
    height:280px;
}

#chart1{background-image:url(http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=p&chd=s:Uf9a&chs=700x280&chl=January|February|March|April);}
#chart1:hover{background-image:url(http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=bhg&chs=700x280&chd=s:el,or&chco=4d89f9,c6d9fd);}

#chart2{background-image:url(http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=p&chd=s:Uf9a&chs=700x280&chdl=May|Juny|July|August);}
#chart2:hover{background-image:url(http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=bhg&chs=700x280&chd=s:el,or&chco=4d89f9,c6d9fd&chbh=15,4,15);}

#chart3{background-image:url(http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=p&chd=s:Uf9a&chs=700x280&chl=September|October|November|December);}
#chart3:hover{background-image:url(http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=bvg&chs=700x280&chd=s:hello,world&chco=4d89f9,c6d9fd&chbh=15,4,15);}
/*]]>*/
</style>

<a id="chart1" class="chart" href="javascript://"><br/></a>
<a id="chart2" class="chart" href="javascript://"><br/></a>
<a id="chart3" class="chart" href="javascript://"><br/></a>
```