# jQuery: applying addClass() or removeClass() to IMG-children of a P

Tags: jquery

I'm a jQuery newbie and am trying to port [a script](http://preferans.de/user.php?id=OK122471020773)

It displays a pie chart image (initial class: "primary") and a bar chart image (initial class: "secondary", not visible) for the same data and viewers can click the chart to flip between pie and bar:

```
<style>
        img.primary   {
                display: inline;
                cursor: pointer;
        }
        img.secondary {
                display: none;
        }
        p.chart:hover, img.secondary {
                display: inline;
                cursor: pointer;
        }
        p.chart:hover, img.primary {
                display: none;
        }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-144.js">
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(function() {
        // remove the "chart" class when the page loads,
        // to disable hover for JavaScript-enabled users
        $("p.chart").removeClass("chart");

        // XXX add a click-handler for P.chart here?
});

// XXX how to rewrite this in jQuery?
function swapImages(container) {
        for (var child in container.childNodes) {
                child = container.childNodes[child];
                if(child.nodeName == "IMG")
                        child.className = (child.className == "primary" ? "secondary" : "primary");
        }
}
</script>
```

And here is an excerpt from the web page:

```
<p class="chart" onclick="swapImages(this);">
<img class="primary" width=700 height=280 src="pie.png">
<img class="secondary" width=700 height=280 src="bar.png">
</p>
```

(Note: [the "p.chart" class is removed on load so that the charts flip between pie and bar on mouse-hover only for JavaScript disabled users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4163523/javascript-method-for-rotating-images-on-a-mouse-click))

But my actual question is about how to rewrite the swapImages() function from pure JavaScript to jQuery. I probably should call:

```
$('p.chart').click(function(e) {
      ....
}
```

and call **addClass("primary")** or **removeClass("secondary")** there, but I'm missing the bit on how to go through all IMG-children of that P.chart.

And do I need to call **$('p.chart').click(....)** or **$('p.chart').each().click(....)** ?

Or maybe I don't need p.chart here anymore and just assign click-handlers directly to the images?

Thank you! Alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this:

```
    $(function(){
      $('p.chart').removeClass(chart);
      $('p:has(img)').click(function(e){
        $("img", this).toggleClass("primary").toggleClass("secondary");
    });
   });
```

If there are two images and you need to toggle the images on each click you can simply use the toggle function:

```
 $(function(){
      $('p.chart').removeClass(chart);
      $('p:has(img)').click(function(e){
         $("img", this).toggle();
        });
   });
```

Edit: Updated the post as per the comment by OP.

Comment: Thank you. How could I remove the "p.chart:hover" class?

Comment: Updated the post. Please check. Also I presume you are including the JS calls in the ready function.